# React: useContext is not updating current state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state, react-context, use-context

i'm actually stuck, i'm trying to find a way to centralize data into my app.
When i'm clicking on the button, `isDisplay` is supposed to be `true` ; the state is changing in my context file but not into the app.

thx !

**Button.tsx**

```
const Button = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);
  const { isDisplay } = state;
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <BootstrapButton
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch({
            type: "DISPLAY_USERS",
            payload: state.users,
          });
        }}
        variant={isDisplay ? "success" : "primary"}
      >
        {isDisplay ? "Albums chargés!" : "Charger les albums"}
      </BootstrapButton>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

**reducer.ts**

```
import { RawUser } from "../interfaces";
import { InitialStateType } from "./context";

type ActionMap<M extends { [index: string]: any }> = {
  [Key in keyof M]: M[Key] extends undefined
    ? {
        type: Key;
      }
    : {
        type: Key;
        payload: M[Key];
      };
};

type UsersPayload = {
  ["LOAD_USERS"]: RawUser[];
  ["DISPLAY_USERS"]: RawUser[];
};

export type LoadUsersActions =
  ActionMap<UsersPayload>[keyof ActionMap<UsersPayload>];

export const loadUsersReducer = (
  state: InitialStateType,
  action: LoadUsersActions
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOAD_USERS":
      return {
        ...state,
        users: action.payload,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case "DISPLAY_USERS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isDisplay: true,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**context.tsx**

```
export type InitialStateType = {
  users: RawUser[];
  isLoading: boolean;
  isDisplay: boolean;
};

export const initialState = {
  users: [],
  isLoading: true,
  isDisplay: false,
};

const AppContext = createContext<{
  state: InitialStateType;
  dispatch: Dispatch<LoadUsersActions>;
}>({
  state: initialState,
  dispatch: () => null,
});

const mainReducer = (data: InitialStateType, action: LoadUsersActions) => ({
  data: loadUsersReducer(data, action),
});

const AppProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(mainReducer, initialState as never);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then((result) => {
      dispatch({ type: "LOAD_USERS", payload: result.data });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
export { AppProvider, AppContext };
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Jumbotron from "react-bootstrap/Jumbotron";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import DefaultButton from "./components/button/Button";
import UserCards from "./components/cards/UserCardsPlaceHolder";
import { AppContext, AppProvider } from "./context/context";
import UsersLoaded from "./components/cards/UsersLoaded";
import { UseGetUsers } from "./api/usersList";

function App() {
  const { state } = useContext(AppContext);
  const { isDisplay } = state;

  console.log(state);

  return (
    <AppProvider>
      <main className="main">
        <Jumbotron fluid>
          <Container fluid="md">
            <h1 className="mb-5">Keep calm, take a deep breath...</h1>
            <DefaultButton />
          </Container>
        </Jumbotron>
        <Container fluid="md">
          {isDisplay ? <UsersLoaded /> : <UserCards />}
        </Container>
      </main>
    </AppProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in `App.tsx` you are accessing an undefined value `isDisplay` - does it compile?

it should be

```
const { state: { isDisplay } } = useContext(AppContext);
```

instead of

```
const { state } = useContext(AppContext);
```

Comment: additionally, if you look at his main reducer, the value of isDisplay is actually available on state.data.isDisplay

Comment: Yes my code is compiling but isDisplay is always false.
Thank you Stefen but my state is not changing here